# Как правильнее организовать структуру игры

Tags: unity3d

Планирую игру из нескольких сцен, хочу использовать события для организации взаимодействия между элементами игры, еще и очень хочется чтобы можно было запустить игру с любой сцены, проинициализировав игру параметрами по умолчанию. Если сделать что игра запускается с первой сцены, то на ней создам объект, который будет подписан на нужные события со всех сцен и уже будет рулить игрой, но если игру запустить со второй сцены, минуя, скажем меню, этот объект не будет создан. Кто тогда будет разруливать? Где взять этот объект?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов реализации очень много. Все зависит от того какие потребности. 
Для прототипов и домашних проктов неплохо себя покзазал подход с использованием Scriptable object для архитектуры проектов:
[Доклад на эту тему](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raQ3iHhE_Kk)

Коротко: вся базовая архитектураная часть выносится из сцен в объекты so. 
Они не привязаны к сценам, это +. 
Они не получают уведомления с которыми привычно работать(Start,Update,etc.)

Comment: Для тех кто предпочитает туториалы на русском о `ScriptableObject` доклад от Валентина Симонова https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1A3XRSS7XUo